# System.IndexOutOfRangeException VB GradeBook

Tags: vb.net

So I get this error when trying to run my code "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"  I am not exactly sure what the issue is.  The user should be able to enter 3 assignment grades and then see the averages

> I marked the line where I get the error with 'THIS IS THE ERROR'

```
Public Class GradeBook
Dim grade(9, 2) As Integer 'Store 10 student grades on 3 tests'
Dim studentCount As Integer = 0 'Number of students entered'

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GradeListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & "Test 1" & vbTab & "Test 2" & vbTab & "Test 3" & vbTab & "Average")
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    grade(studentCount, 0) = Convert.ToInt32(Assignment1TextBox.Text)
    grade(studentCount, 1) = Convert.ToInt32(Assignment2TextBox.Text)
    grade(studentCount, 2) = Convert.ToInt32(Assignment3TextBox.Text)

    Dim output As String = "Student " & studentCount & vbTab
    For column = 0 To grade.GetUpperBound(1)
        If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            output &= vbTab & LetterGrade(grade(studentCount, column))
        Else
            output &= vbTab & grade(studentCount, column)
        End If
    Next
    output &= vbTab & CalculateStudentAverage(studentCount)
    GradeListBox.Items.Add(output)
    studentCount += 1
    AverageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
    displayBarChart()
End Sub
Function LetterGrade(ByVal grade As Double) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Select Case grade
        Case Is >= 90
            output = "A"
        Case Is >= 80
            output = "B"
        Case Is >= 70
            output = "C"
        Case Is >= 60
            output = "D"
        Case Is >= 50
            output = "E"

    End Select
    Return output
End Function
Function CalculateStudentAverage(ByVal row As Integer) As String
    Dim gradeTotal As Integer = 0
    For column = 0 To grade.GetUpperBound(1)
        gradeTotal += grade(row, column) 'THIS IS THE ERROR'
    Next
    Dim studentAverage As String = String.Empty
    If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        studentAverage = LetterGrade(gradeTotal / (grade.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))
    Else
        studentAverage = String.Format("{0:F}", (gradeTotal / grade.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))
    End If
    Return studentAverage
End Function
Function CalculateClassAverage() As String
    Dim classTotal As Integer = 0
    For row = 0 To studentCount - 1
        For column = 0 To grade.GetUpperBound(1)
            classTotal += grade(row, column)
        Next
    Next
    Dim classAverage As String = String.Empty
    If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        classAverage = LetterGrade(classTotal / (studentCount * (grade.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)))
    Else
        classAverage = String.Format("{0:F}", (classTotal / (studentCount * (grade.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))))
    End If
    Return classAverage
End Function
Sub displayBarChart()
    GradeListBox.Items.Clear()
    GradeListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & "Test 1" & vbTab & "Test 2" & vbTab & "Test 3" & vbTab & "Average")
    For row = 0 To studentCount - 1
        Dim output As String = "Student " & row & vbTab
        For column = 0 To grade.GetUpperBound(1)
            If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                output &= vbTab & LetterGrade(grade(row, column))
            Else
                output &= vbTab & (grade(row, column))
            End If
        Next
        output &= vbTab & CalculateStudentAverage(studentCount)
        GradeListBox.Items.Add(output)
        studentCount += 1
        AverageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
        displayBarChart()
        Assignment1TextBox.Clear()
        Assignment2TextBox.Clear()
        Assignment3TextBox.Clear()
        If studentCount = grade.GetUpperBound(0) + 1 Then
            InputGradeGroupBox.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The issue is that the index is out of range. You should set breakpoints and debug it yourself. This question is also way too far from a minimal example.

Comment: It seems that in your `Sub displayBarChart()` you are incrementing the number of students: `studentCount += 1`, which has a class scope and references the number of students (or rows) and is also used in the  enumeration in the same routine (you should use `row` as reference). That method, `Sub displayBarChart()`, is to reconsider completely. You should also check, when `SubmitButton()` is clicked, that the number of students is <= of the array hardcoded bounds.

Comment: Put the `End Class` in with the rest of the code block

Comment: Good job on the Select Case.

Comment: The sub `displayBarChart` is calling itself, so in all likelihood, as `studentCount is being incremented in that sub, you will end up with `studentCount` being greater than 9.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I suspect you're going about it in a way not suited to OOP. Using arrays for multiple peices of data is prone to error and harder to maintain later.

Lets have a think about how you want to represent your data. You have a bunch of students. In a more complete example each student would have a name, personal details such as address, a list of the courses they're taking and for each course, a list of assignments and scores for each assignment which can also be represented as a grade.

So in essence you have a class called `Student` and the various bits of information are properties of that student.

Finally you have a list of these students

In your code, you simply have a student number and three assignment scores.

Your basic student class should have the properties of Number, Test1Score, Test2Score and Test3Score. You would also want to be able to get the grade from each score, the average of all the scores and the average of all the grades.

The code below defines the `Student` class with that information in mind

```
Friend Class Student

    Public Property Number As Integer

    Public Property Test1Score As Integer

    Public Property Test2Score As Integer

    Public Property Test3Score As Integer


    Public Function Test1Grade() As String
        Return LetterGrade(Test1Score)
    End Function

    Public Function Test2Grade() As String
        Return LetterGrade(Test2Score)
    End Function

    Public Function Test3Grade() As String
        Return LetterGrade(Test3Score)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function LetterGrade(ByVal grade As Double) As String
        Dim output As String = ""
        Select Case grade
            Case Is >= 90
                output = "A"
            Case Is >= 80
                output = "B"
            Case Is >= 70
                output = "C"
            Case Is >= 60
                output = "D"
            Case Is >= 50
                output = "E"
            Case Else
                output = "F"
        End Select
        Return output
    End Function

    Friend Function AverageScore() As Double
        Return (Test1Score + Test2Score + Test3Score) / 3
    End Function

    Friend Function AverageGrade() As String
        Dim avgscore As Double = AverageScore()
        Return LetterGrade(avgscore)
    End Function

End Class
```

The function LetterGrade is `Shared` so that it can be used in your main form to calculate the average grade for the entire class.

OK Next think about how you want your program to work. You'll need a list of students, so at the beginning of your form class , you'll need this..

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Students As New List(Of Student)
```

This way, instead of trying to keep track of your variable `studentCount` you can just use the `.Count` property of the List e.g `Students.Count`. You wont need to any adding to it as the `Students` list keeps track of it automatically.

Next, you'll want the function that calculates the average score/grade of the class..

```
Function CalculateClassAverage() As String
    Dim classTotal As Integer = 0
    For Each tmpStudent As Student In Students
        With tmpStudent
            classTotal += .Test1Score + .Test2Score + .Test3Score
        End With
    Next
    Dim classAverage As String = String.Empty
    If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        classAverage = Student.LetterGrade((classTotal / Students.Count) / 3)
    Else
        classAverage = String.Format("{0:F}", (classTotal / (Students.Count)) / 3)
    End If
    Return classAverage
End Function
```

As you can see, there are a number of differences here because of the way your data is stored, but you should be able to follow it. One difference is the `With` statement, this allows you to save on typing. inside the `With.. End With` block, instead of typing `tmpstudent.Test1Score` etc, you can just type `.Test1Score`

The other thing of note is this line ..

classAverage = Student.LetterGrade( ... etc

You may think that there has been no declaration of a variable called `Student`. There IS a class, but not a variable. What this is actually doing is calling the `LetterGrade` function that is shared in the `Student` class definition.. Have a look at shared functions.

Next is the code to display the information in the ListBox. I haven't changed the name even though it is misleading btw.

```
Sub displayBarChart()
    GradeListBox.Items.Clear()
    GradeListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & "Test 1" & vbTab & "Test 2" & vbTab & "Test 3" & vbTab & "Average")
    For Each tmpstudent As Student In Students
        Dim output As String = "Student " & tmpstudent.Number & vbTab
        With tmpstudent
            If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                output &= .Test1Grade & vbTab & .Test2Grade & vbTab & .Test3Grade & vbTab & .AverageGrade
            Else
                output &= .Test1Score & vbTab & .Test2Score & vbTab & .Test3Score & vbTab & .AverageScore
            End If
        End With
        GradeListBox.Items.Add(output)
        AverageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
    Next
    If Students.Count = 10 Then
        InputGradeGroupBox.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

More use of the `With..End With` statements again, but the rest should be straighforward to follow.

A little extra bit of code.. When you click on the `LetterRadioButton`, the data in the listBox and ClassAveragelabel are refreshed with the appropriate letters/grades

```
Private Sub LetterRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LetterRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    AverageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
    displayBarChart()
End Sub
```

Finally, to bring it all together, you have the code for the button click..

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    Dim tmpStudent As New Student With {.Number = Students.Count + 1,
                                        .Test1Score = Convert.ToDouble(Assignment1TextBox.Text),
                                        .Test2Score = Convert.ToDouble(Assignment2TextBox.Text),
                                        .Test3Score = Convert.ToDouble(Assignment3TextBox.Text)}

    Dim output As String = "Student " & tmpStudent.Number & vbTab

    With tmpStudent
        If LetterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            output &= vbTab & .Test1Grade & vbTab & .Test2Grade & vbTab & .Test3Grade
        Else
            output &= vbTab & .Test1Score & vbTab & .Test2Score & vbTab & .Test3Score
        End If
    End With
    Students.Add(tmpStudent)
    If LetterRadioButton.Checked Then
        output &= vbTab & tmpStudent.AverageGrade
    Else
        output &= vbTab & tmpStudent.AverageScore
    End If
    GradeListBox.Items.Add(output)
    AverageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
    displayBarChart()
    Assignment1TextBox.Clear()
    Assignment2TextBox.Clear()
    Assignment3TextBox.Clear()
End Sub
```

Hopefully in addition to my comment to your question, this provides a slightly better insight of OOP.